# sed and variables

Tags: sed

I know this question has been asked multiple times but the solution doesn't work for me.

I have 2 files: 1_all and 2_ovo. They both contain a list of items. 1_all contains items from 2_ovo plus other items. I need to delete all the items from 1_all which are the same as in 2_ovo. This is what I've got:

```
for i in 2_ovo
   do
sed -i "/$i/d" 1_all
done
```

So take the value from 2_ovo and delete this value from 1_all.

I know that variables in sed should be handled with double quotes, yet the command does nothing at all. If I substitute $i with a real value, the value is deleted from the file as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: The loop will be executed one time with `i` set to `2_ovo`. You don't read the file contents at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file so you can execute the loop.

```
for i in `cat /path/to/file/2_ovo`
do
    sed -i "/$i/d" 1_all
done
```

Comment: ... at least as long as `2_ovo` doesn't contain any `"` or `/` or `\` or `*` or ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting `sed` for each line of `2_ovo`, you can use `grep` with options `-Fxf 2_ovo` to use the file as list of literal lines to match and `-v` to invert the match:

```
grep -vFxf 2_ovo 1_all > 3_only_the_rest
```